# Changing radio button values and adding classes with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, radio-button

I'm trying to user jquery to add/remove a class on a pair of divs which consist of a background images. The div/image is meant to act as a radio box for a pair of hidden radio boxes.

When clicking the div/image the script should apply the class 'selected' to the clicked div and remove it (if necessary) from the other; and select the appropriate hidden radio button.

To the best of my knowledge the below script should work, but isn't and I'm not really sure what I'm doing incorrectly right now. Any ideas stackers?

SCRIPT

```
$("div#like").click(function() {
    var $radios = $('input:radio[name=vote]');
    $("div#dislike").removeClass("selected");
    $("div#like").addClass("selected");
        $radios.filter('[value=likes]').attr('checked', true);
});

$("div#dislike").click(function() {
    var $radios = $('input:radio[name=vote]');
    $("div#like").removeClass("selected");
    $("div#dislike").addClass("selected");
        $radios.filter('[value=likes]').attr('checked', true);
});
```

HTML

```
<form action="createComment.php" method="post">
<div id="like" ><input class="like" type="radio" name="vote" value="likes" /></div>&nbsp;
<div id="dislike" ><input class="dislike" type="radio" name="vote" value="dislikes" /></div><br/>
</form>
```

[EDIT 3:07PM]
What if I went this route?

```
$("div#like").click(function() {
    var $radios = $('input:radio[name=vote]');
        $("div#dislike").removeClass("selected");
        $("div#like").addClass("selected");
        $radios.filter('[value=likes]').attr('checked', true);
        $radios.filter('[value=dislikes]').attr('checked', false);
    });

$("div#dislike").click(function() {
    var $radios = $('input:radio[name=vote]');
        $("div#like").removeClass("selected");
        $("div#dislike").addClass("selected");
        $radios.filter('[value=dislikes]').attr('checked', true);
        $radios.filter('[value=likes]').attr('checked', false);
    });
```

Comment: Does it work for you now? You've corrected which button you set to checked, so it appears to me it should. Actually, it won't work - you should leave the attr("checked", true) in there.

Comment: See the jquery docs for setting checked: http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_check.2Funcheck_a_checkbox_input_or_radio_button.3F

Comment: It works on its own, but when I integrate it into my site it still doesn't.

Comment: What happens? Additionally, setting the other button to false is unnecessary - the browser will automatically handle that for you when another button gets checked.

Comment: From what I'm seeing, the radio buttons are not being set to true when the div is clicked (have made them visible to test).

Comment: new code http://jsfiddle.net/cu2y8/15/

Comment: Also, the class is not being set to selected for the wrapper div.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I made a local version of it (hard to check generated source with jsfiddle.) Make sure you're checking generated source, not just source - install the web developer toolbar on Firefox and use the View Source | View Generated Source option. The class was set and the values were set to checked on the correct input when I viewed it.

Comment: Also, the radio buttons were visibly checked for me when I removed the display css style.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing in jsfiddle, but still not seeing it work in my integrated page, something in my master is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set the attribute `checked="checked"` using javascript. Instead, use

`radioButton.checked = true`

Using jquery you can do,

```
$radios.filter('[value=likes]').get(0).checked = true
```

Here is a nice little example for you, http://jsfiddle.net/cu2y8/6/

Comment: Actually, setting the checked attribute using javascript will not update it. You need to set the checked property of the radio element to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

You set checked to true on the [value=likes] button regardless of which div gets clicked.

Make sure you select the [value=dislikes] button when the dislike div is clicked.